# Don't you think all of these rules and reputation crap is just a bit much? Are you people nuts or what?

Tags: hybrid-bike, upgrades, speed

A person was asking about the best way to make his hybrid bike more like a road bike.  I am headed in that direction myself, and some of the ideas in response to the question were very helpful.  But what wasn't too helpful was the cockiness and arrogance of some of you country-club cycle elitist who said "just buy a road bike."  Uh, road bikes are expensive, and not everyone can afford one.  This is the main reason why upgrading your hybrid to make it more faster, lighter, or aerodynamic yet still have enough toughness for a bike trail seems to me a really smart idea that I encourage more people to do.  If you don't like that idea, then perhaps you should change your website name to the Road Bike Elitist Snobs.  That would probably be more fitting.

Comment: You might consider [chat] or https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/   This is a question about the site, not about bikes.

Comment: Do remember to up-vote the answers that you found helpful in the other posts too, that lets other future readers know what is likely a good answer. Downvotes require a rep of 125, and only 15 rep to do upvotes.  Downvotes should be used for replies/answer that are wrong or misleading etc.  (fixed)

Comment: We had a lot of those questions. Please post an answer with advise on how to modify a hybrid to a road bike. If you ask such a question and only want to hear answers that you already have yourself asking is utterly pointless.

Comment: You're the arrogant "elitist" here who's confusing your ignorance with expertise.  *This is the main reason why upgrading your hybrid to make it more faster, lighter, or aerodynamic yet still have enough toughness for a bike trail seems to me a really smart idea that I encourage more people to do.*  Do you also advise using a hammer for a screwdriver?  What you're describing as "smart" is merely trying to take the square peg of a hybrid bicycle and force it into the round hole of gravel or cyclecross bike.  You get a really bad gravel or cyclecross bike because it wasn't designed for that use

Comment: And as others have noted, it's probably more expensive anyway....

Comment: Two other points - keeping a set of rules is what stops any website from degenerating into a comments-based forum (just look at what is happening here already!), and we have a strong MTB representation too. About the only sensible modification is faster-rolling tires (which sacrifices off-road performance anyways) - anything else would be better spent towards a proper road bike.

Answer (score 7):

The reason that buying a road bike is better than adapting a hybrid bike to *be* a road bike is very much related to economic factors. Therefore the complaint that "not everyone can afford one"  is poor thinking.

In reality, the process of adapting a hybrid bike to be a completely different bike is actually rather expensive and will not even be value for money as the end result is compromised.

Imagination time, thinking about costs:

New handlebars: $40?
New slick tyres: $80 pair?
New shifters: $200? these are pricey even for basic ones
New cables: $10?
New bar tape: $15?
Compatible brake calipers (really!): $50?

Total conversion: pushing **$400**?

Compare that to an entry level road bike (cos poor) - $500? minus equity in hybrid (sell it) = **$300** cost for buying road bike and it's *brand new*, no wear and tear.

I'm not saying those costs are real but they are ball park, so the economic argument against buying a new road bike is a bad one, while a converted hybrid bike is not as good at being a road bike as... a road bike.

So if you are thinking of adapting a bike to make it a bit zippier on the road as opposed to the trail, that's cool, nobody will mind if you do that. Just think about what the total costs will be for your own project up front, and if it would only be a little bit more money to buy a different bike (it could be a used bike of course), then we're only too glad to have helped save you putting cash into a wasteful project if you're looking to get the best value for money.

Answer (score 5):

The thing is: You can’t just slap a drop bar onto a hybrid or MTB and expect it to behave like a proper road bike. Usually the frame will be too long, unless you purposefully got a smaller frame. In addition, getting all the new components (handlebar, brifters, maybe even new derailleur etc.) is expensive.

So in a way “get a road bike if you want a road bike” is often the best answer and not meant as an insult.

Of course you can improve a hybrid or MTB for road use by getting faster, tread-less (slick) tires, reducing weight, getting rid of suspension fork etc. But you won’t get a road bike.